# MySQL Booking system: Getting available rooms

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my query for locating available rooms in a simple hotel booking system.

My table structure looks like the following:

`hotels`
`hotelroomtypes` (intersects a hotel, with a room and a roomtype)
`bookings`
`orders`

There is more to it, but the use of the other tables sums themselves up in the query, which looks like the following:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
         hotels.HotelName
        ,hotels.HotelID
        ,hotels.Address
        ,hotels.Description
        ,images.URL
        ,roomtypes.Price
        ,roomtypes.RoomtypeName
        ,roomtypes.RoomtypeID
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT hotelroomtypes.HRID) AS AvailableRooms

    FROM hotelroomtypes
    INNER JOIN hotels ON (
        hotelroomtypes.HotelID = hotels.HotelID
        AND
        hotels.CountryID = 1 // e.g. United States
    )
    INNER JOIN roomtypes ON (
        hotelroomtypes.RoomtypeID = roomtypes.RoomtypeID
        AND
        roomtypes.RoomtypeID = 1 // e.g. Suite
    )
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN bookings ON (
        hotelroomtypes.HRID NOT IN (
            SELECT HRID FROM bookings
            WHERE bookings.From BETWEEN '2015-06-13' and '2015-06-16'
            OR bookings.To BETWEEN '2015-06-13' and '2015-06-16'
        )
    )
    INNER JOIN images ON (
        hotels.ImageID = images.ImageID
    )
    GROUP BY 
        hotels.HotelName
    HAVING COUNT(hotelroomtypes.HRID) > 0
    ORDER BY hotels.HotelName ASC, AvailableRooms ASC
```

Now my problems lay with getting the correct number of booked rooms, and also hiding the hotel from the query if all the rooms are taken.

I used to do this by having an `INNER JOIN` on `bookings`, but when I then had an empty `bookings` table, the query failed 100% and didn't show any hotels.

With `LEFT` joins, I had some false positives at times, but currently using these types of joins all return EVERY room the hotel has or none at all.

`INNER` naturally returns no hotels if there are no bookings present, as expected. Which is what I was using earlier.

How can I correcly structure this query to give me an exact amount of available rooms on each hotel, as well as only returning hotels which have available rooms, even if there are no bookings to search through?

edit for table structures:

```
Hotels:
 _________________________________________________________________
| hotelid | hotelname | countryid | description | otherfieldshere |
|_________|___________|___________|_____________|_________________|
|    1    |  example  |     1     |  something  |    something    |
|_________|___________|___________|_____________|_________________|

Hotelroomtypes:
 ______________________________________
| hrid | hotelid | roomtypeid | roomid |
|______|_________|____________|________|
|  1   |    1    |     1      |   1    |
|______|_________|____________|________|

Bookings:
 _______________________________________________
| bookingid |    from    |     to     | orderid |
|___________|____________|____________|_________|
|    1      | 2015-05-13 | 2015-05-16 |    1    |
|___________|____________|____________|_________|

Orders:

 ________________________________________
| orderid | reference |      email       |
|_________|___________|__________________|
|    1    |   12345   | some@example.com |
|_________|___________|__________________|

Rooms:

 _____________________
| roomid | roomnumber |
|________|____________|
|   1    |    500     |
|________|____________|
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: How do I structure my query to get the correct number of available rooms, as well as hiding a hotel if all the rooms available in it is booked.

Comment: Updated the post with my actual question.

Comment: can you post structure of all tables?

Comment: did it just now, @Lupin

Comment: I restructured my query so that there was no extra join on bookings, and I think that did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems alcohol and problem solving isn't really an option when you've been working for 7 hours straight without a break.

I restructured my query to the following:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
         hotels.HotelName
        ,hotels.HotelID
        ,hotels.Address
        ,hotels.Description
        ,images.URL
        ,roomtypes.Price
        ,roomtypes.RoomtypeName
        ,roomtypes.RoomtypeID
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT hotelroomtypes.HRID) AS AvailableRooms

    FROM hotels
    INNER JOIN hotelroomtypes ON (
        hotelroomtypes.HotelID = hotels.HotelID
        AND
        hotels.CountryID = ?
        AND
        hotelroomtypes.HRID NOT IN (
            SELECT HRID FROM bookings
            WHERE bookings.From BETWEEN ? and ?
            OR bookings.To BETWEEN ? and ?
        )
    )
    INNER JOIN roomtypes ON (
        hotelroomtypes.RoomtypeID = roomtypes.RoomtypeID
        AND
        roomtypes.RoomtypeID = ?
    )
    INNER JOIN images ON (
        hotels.ImageID = images.ImageID
    )
    GROUP BY 
        hotels.HotelName
    HAVING COUNT(hotelroomtypes.HRID) > 0
    ORDER BY hotels.HotelName ASC, AvailableRooms ASC
```

Which actually solved my problem.